.NET SDK Project Debugging Properties
I am upgrading a solution from the older project file format to the new SDK style format.  I have it updated and working but I'm looking to see where I can "clean up" some unnecessary things.  One of the things I'm wondering about is related to debugging.  I have several conditional statements on different build configs.  Some of the tags in here I'm wondering if they are not needed but I couldn't find enough info to tell for sure.  Here is an example of one conditional:
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'D2024'">
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>..\..\..\BuildD2024</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;r2024</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

and another:
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'R2024'">
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>..\..\..\Build2024</OutputPath>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

In the first one it has the DebugSymbols tag and the second has the Optimize tag.  If I understand right, DebugSymbols is supposed to determine if a pdb file is generated for the build and Optimize does something to optimize the build for release/production.  The first conditional is a debugging build config and the second is a release so that would be correct.  However, the question is if these are really necessary.  I saw some things that said the system will automatically turn off pdb for release builds and on for debug builds, but I couldn't find anything that said how the system figures out what is a debug and what is a release build.
I can leave these tags in if they are needed and everything seems to be working fine as is but if they are redundant it would be nice to clean out and simplify the csproj file as much as possible.
